# How to update entity using spring-data neo4j

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

My problem is when I'm trying to update entity using GraphRepository 'save' method, all my fields, that was not changed, are being rewritten with null values.

I make PUT request with only id and name, because I want change User's name, but save method automatically changes password field to null value. I wanna update only dirty values. How can I achieve this? Maybe there is some kind of merge or update methods?

My entity class looks like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

@GraphId Long id;

String name;
String password;

    public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

    public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@JsonIgnore
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

My repository class looks like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {
    public User findById(Long id);
}
```

Comment: To update entity fields just modify the values inside a transaction, no need to call the save method.

Comment: Can you add some code example, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Transactional
public void update(Long id, String name) {
    User user = repository.findById(id);

    if (user != null) {
        user.setName(name);
    }
}
```